# Converting integer to string with atoi/sprintf

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, casting

This is not my whole code I just sum it up to be easy to see. I have no problem to convert the string into an integer but I cannot convert the integer into a string.
The program just crashes. Here is the code. Look at the line with `itoa`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZEX 49
#define SIZEY 6

int main() {
    size_t x, y;
    char *a[50][7];
    char name[50][100];
    char surname[50][100];
    char IN[50][100];
    char YOB[50][100];
    char usname[50][100];
    char pass[50][100];
    char totamount[50][100];

    for (x = 0; x <= SIZEX; x++) {         
        a[x][0] = name[x];
        a[x][1] = surname[x];
        a[x][2] = IN[x];
        a[x][3] = YOB[x];
        a[x][4] = usname[x];
        a[x][5] = totamount[x];
        a[x][6] = pass[x];
    }
    printf("\nPlease enter the name of the new user\n");
    scanf(" %s", a[0][0]);

    printf("Please enter the surname of the new user\n");
    scanf(" %s", a[0][1]);

    printf("Please enter the Identity Number of the new user\n");
    scanf(" %s", a[0][2]);

    printf("Please enter the year of birth of the new user\n");
    scanf(" %s", a[0][3]);

    printf("Please enter the username of the new user\n");
    scanf(" %s", a[0][4]);

    strcpy(a[0][6], a[0][4]);
    strrev(a[0][6]);

    a[0][5] = "0";

    int z;
    z = atoi(a[0][5]);
    z = z + strlen(a[0][4]) * 10;

    itoa(z, a[0][5], 10);
    //sprintf(a[0][5], "%d", z);

    printf("%s\n", a[0][5]);
    printf("%d\n", z);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strrev` nor `itoa` are standard.

Comment: strrev and itoa are not given by the ANSI C committe. So they are just compiler extensions that some compilers support.

Comment: what about sprintf?
strrev is working fine.
Can you tell me if I wrote the itoa and the sprint line correctly?

Comment: Note: `" "` not needed in `scanf(" %s",...`  `"%s"` skips leading white-space by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing this:

```
a[0][5]="0";
```

You are assigning to `a[0][5]` a pointer to a readonly memory containing string literal `"0"`.

Here:

```
itoa( z, a[0][5],10 );
```

you are attempting to write there, giving you memory access violation.

Comment: I am confused.So how I write this correctly.How can i have memory access

Comment: Probably, instead of `a[0][5]="0"` you should use `strcpy` (if I understand your logic correctly).

Comment: like strcpy(a[0][5],"0"); ?

Comment: Yes. Or just `a[0][5][0]='0'; a[0][5][1]='\0'`. But it is ugly.

Comment: Thank you so much* ? My English are so bad :p

Comment: Both are equally correct. Anyway, you are welcome, and can just accept the answer.

Comment: Seems like you would be better off defining a struct containing name, surname, etc., and then creating an array of 50 of those structs.

Comment: yeah you are right but we haven't learnt structs in the class yet so i cant use it :/